# i just start learning vuejs. how to return output from vuejs to flask in single page?

Tags: vue.js, flask

i just testing the vuejs tutorial with flask with single page. i use  vuejs cdn in app.py

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<h1>{{ message }}</h1>
```

javascript

```
<script setup>
    import { ref } from 'vue'
    const message = ref('Hello World!')
    console.log(message.value) // "Hello World!"
    message.value = 'Changed'
</script>
```

Comment: Your code is the "Hello World!" starter example for Vue.js and does not generate any output.

Comment: can you show me a example?

Comment: Example of what? It's not clear what do you want to achieve. Please describe your goal more precise and provide the code for your attempt to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

To send something to backend you will need a HTML Form or an AJAX Post request.

Check the tutorials:

- [Vue 3 - HTTP POST Request Examples](https://jasonwatmore.com/vue-3-http-post-request-examples)
- [How To Use Web Forms in a Flask Application](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-web-forms-in-a-flask-application#step-2-setting-up-forms)

Here is an example of the simple POST request with a JSON body using fetch

```
const requestOptions = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    body: JSON.stringify({ name: 'Vue 3 POST Request Example' })
};
fetch('https://testapi.jasonwatmore.com/products', requestOptions)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => product.value = data);
```

Example of Flask HTML Form

```
<form method="post">
    <label for="title">Title</label>
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="title"
           placeholder="Message title"
           value="{{ request.form['title'] }}"></input>
    <br>

    <label for="content">Message Content</label>
    <br>
    <textarea name="content"
              placeholder="Message content"
              rows="15"
              cols="60"
              >{{ request.form['content'] }}</textarea>
    <br>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```